# Undirected graphs with choice

Tags: graph-algorithm, calculus

I must make an algorithm using choice using two undirected graphs G1=(V1,E1) and G2=(V2,E2), using rule that the number of V1=V2 and E1=E2. The question is that the graphs G1 and G2 are isomorphic? I must prove that using an algorithm ( with choice )

I proved theoretic that graphs being isomorphic but how I will prove implementing an algorithm?

Comment: I would like to see your theoretical proof that the two graphs are isomorphic; I believe it to be incorrect. Adding the graph-algorithm tag.

Comment: Why do you think is incorrect? because it is not probably a NP problem?

Comment: Because if I understand the question correctly, |V1| = |V2|, |E1| = |E2| is insufficient to prove isomorphism.

Comment: You could easily draw two graphs on paper, each having 4 nodes and 2 edges and yet fail to be isomorphic. Graph1: `A===B===C      D` and take Graph2: `A===B     C===D` clearly they are not isomorphic. As far as i can tell, for `|V| > 3` and `|E| > 1` it is possible that the graphs are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Two isomorphic graphs have the same number of vertices and edges, but it is not sufficient. In addition, they must have the same degree sequence and also there should be a series of elementary matrix operations such that you can convert adjacency matrix of one to the other. See [this link](http://www.dharwadker.org/tevet/isomorphism/) for a detailed algorithm and in-depth discussion.